# Setting variable to true on click - Doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with 2 simple tabs. The tabs are showing if disable_function = false.

At the end of the page I have a simple trigger which I want to set the variable disable_function = true so that the tabs won't work - when ever the trigger is ON.

I tried few ways but it didn't seem to work.

Here is a fiddle if you want to have a look of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/db7tK/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have disable_function defined in the scope of document.ready.
not as a global.
move it out of 'jQuery(document).ready(function(){'

EDIT:

```
<script>
var disable_function = false;
jQuery(document).ready(function(){....
```

Comment: Well if i set var disable_function = true; from the beginning it seems that the tabs aint working.

Comment: If I would had to move it outside 'jQuery(document).ready(function(){' to make it work then it should work if had it on true from the beginning?

Comment: i'm sorry, but i don't understand what you are saying. if you just write: var disable_function = false;
jQuery(document).ready(function(){...
then it should function correctly.